# Is that possible for Apple Watch to be notified only when both Apple Watch and iPhone are locked?

Tags: ios, notifications, watchkit, apple-watch

Generally, if your iPhone is unlocked, you get notifications on your iPhone, instead of your Apple Watch.

If your iPhone is locked or asleep, and your Apple Watch is unlocked and on your wrist, you get notifications on your Apple Watch.

In my app, I want to notify to user in Apple Watch when both iPhone and Apple Watch are locked. Is that possible to notify in Apple Watch only when both Apple Watch and iPhone are locked?

Comment: AFAIK it´s not possible.

Answer (score 0):

No it it snot possible. iOS decides which device receives the push notification, as you noticed, depending on which one is being used, etc.

Comment: If my mobile is somewhere in my home and I wear iwatch , if I got notification that will go to iphone if iwatch is locked. This is drawback right? Can't I overcome this?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. It is designed to work this way to prevent unwanted eyes seeing your push notifications since they can contain sensitive data. It will only show on the Apple Watch if unlocked. You cannot change this as a developer. A user can opt to not lock their watch.